# VS2013 Ultimate Preview + Web Essentials 2013 RC not compiling LESS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm not getting any errors, I just can't for the life of me get CSS out of the LESS files in my solution on build or save.  I've restarted everything and installed from scratch to no avail - it's just not working.  What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have the Web Essentials 2013 RC extension installed and updated?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have Web Essentials installed and the settings in Options|Web Essentials | Less (last 3 options all set to their default values of true) appear to be all correct but I get no preview and no css output when I save (or build for that matter).

Comment: Since both VS 2013 and Web Essentials 2013 are RTM'd, the only way to get support for this issue would be to update to the RTM versions and try again.  There have been countless fixes, since VS 2013 Preview etc.

Comment: just updated from 1.3 to 1.6 and LESS stopped to work

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled the Web Essentials Extension then installed the Version 2.5 for Update 4 at https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases

And it worked again.